# V8js installed but not working

Tags: php, php-7, php-extension, v8js

Good morning,
I tried to install V8js from this link
https://github.com/linux-on-ibm-z/docs/wiki/Building-V8-libraries-5.xi

I have add the path in php.ini

```
extension = /root/v8test/v8/out/s390x.release/lib.target/libv8.so
```

I have also try with https://github.com/phpv8/v8js/blob/php7/README.Linux.md the first method and the last method

```
cd /tmp
git clone https://github.com/phpv8/v8js.git
cd v8js
phpize
./configure --with-v8js=/opt/v8
make
make test
sudo make install
```

And add `extension=v8js.so` to php.ini

Then I restart apache and in my phpInfo I don't see V8Js.
It is the good  php.ini because when I change the Default timezone in this file, it works.

I don't see what I am missing I am under linux Mint with php7

Thanks

Comment: check error log

Comment: Thank I was not looking the good log i was looking /var/log/apache2/access.log instead of error.log. The problem was that the so file was not in the expected directory.

Answer (score 0):

The error was that after :

```
cd /tmp
git clone https://github.com/phpv8/v8js.git
cd v8js
phpize
./configure --with-v8js=/opt/v8
make
make test
sudo make install
```

I had to copy `v8js.so` into the folder `/usr/lib/php/20151012`

```
sudo cp /tmp/v8js/modules/v8js.so /usr/lib/php/20151012/
```

The name of the folder can be find in phpinfo at line `extension_dir`. error can be view in the file `/var/log/apache2/error.log`